# Azure Machine Learning pin python version on notebook

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Looking for a way to use Python 3.10 on a compute resource associated to Azure ML Studio
It appears 3.10 is available with ML Studio and we select 3.10 with SDK2 from the kernel selection dropdown but when running a "python --version" on the terminal, it says v 3.8.5. Is there a way to get Azure ML Studio to use a different version of Python?
We've tried the environment option but had no luck.
Looks like the kernel selection option does not match what the OS is running, perhaps it's designed to work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the selected conda environment. There will be multiple environments created when you create a compute instance.

To see, run the conda command below:

```
%%sh
conda info --env
```

This lists the environments present.

However, if you run this in a notebook, you cannot see which environment you are in.

So, execute these commands in the terminal.

Open the compute and select **Terminal**.

[image]

There, you will see the default is Python 3.8.

[image]

You can also see this with the commands below:

```
conda info --env

or

conda env list

or 

echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV
```

Output:

[image]

Whenever you select the kernel, it doesn't switch the environment in the terminal; that only changes in the notebook Python code.

Whatever command you run in a subprocess or using `%%sh`, it takes the default Python environment.

```py
import sys, platform
print(sys.version)
print(platform.python_version())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, l was getting all kinds of errors creating a new conda environment but as you show, they are all created already. All I had to do is switch to the 3.10 environment with "conda activate azureml_pyton3.10_sdkv2" on the compute resource.

Comment: Yeah. Source activate env. See conda documentation for it.